# Pnumatic sulinoid with multiple outputs

Tags: mechanism

I can't figure out what solenoid I would use. Everything I search for comes up with cylinders. Not sure if it's even a sulinoid that I need.

I'd like to have 8 hoses connected to a compressor. I'd like to control which hose releases air to push something off a conveyor belt. Like the image below.

[image][image]

Comment: does the mechanism have to be pneumatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the wrong thing.

This is a solenoid
[image]

This is what you want, a solenoid operated valve.

[image]

Comment: yep that helped a lot, thanks. I found another image that I added to the original comment. What allows there to be 6 sulinoid valves connected to one source? Or is it one product?

Comment: Ok figured it out. 3 way pneumatic sulenoid values on a manifold. Thanks!